Setup changes (question for teammate)
When is it okay for two (2) Admins to be logged into Salesforce making changes in Setup at the same time?

It depends on exactly what changes are being made, and whether the admins are differently updating the same settings or other metadata. Basically, yes it is fine for two or more admins (or other types of user) to be using setup to make changes, but the work needs to be coordinated, and ideally should be done in a non-production org for testing and verification first. Further, it would be ideal if all changes were captured in source control (e.g. via the use of Salesforce's DevOps Center or similar tools).

In general, most settings can be configured by multiple administrators at the same time, although there are some limitations. If one administrator starts an operation that requires an Org Lock, and another administrator attempts to start an operation that requires an Org Lock, they will get the 'Org Administration Locked' error. You'll want to read the article for more information, but in summary, Org Locks occur when a large amount of data needs to be updated, such as changes to the Role Hierarchy or running a Deployment. However, there are different Org Locks. For example, one administrator could make sharing settings change, while a second administrator creates custom fields or objects.
